# res.send is not waiting for my async function to finish before sending the response to the front end on my Express server app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, puppeteer

I am trying to create full stack app that lets the user input the URL and captures the screenshot using Puppeteer. On my backend express server I am using app.post to send the response to the front end which creates the image for download.

Here's my backend:

```
app.post('/api/screenshot', (req, res) => {
  const { url } = req.body

  let screenshot = takeScreenshot(url)
  res.send({ result: screenshot })
  // next()
})

async function takeScreenshot(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
  const screenshot = await page.screenshot()

  await browser.close();
  return screenshot;
}
```

My front end JS has an event listener for the ss-btn. When it is clicked, it triggers the post request to the backend which runs the takeScreenshot function. Then it generates the link for the download

```
$("#ss-btn").on("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var url = $("#url").val().trim();

  $.post("/api/screenshot", { url: url })
    .then(res => {
      const { result } = res
      const blob = new Blob([result], { type: 'image/png' })
      const link = document.createElement('a')
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      link.download = `your-file-name.png`
      link.click()
    })
});
```

Right now, when I click the ss-btn, I get the popup right away asking where I want to save the image. But it doesn't look like the screenshot is being sent back to the front end. The png file is corrupted and I cannot open it.

TIA

Comment: Hey Kevin. Looks like you forgot to put `await` before the function. As in: `let screenshot = await takeScreenshot(url)`. (you'll also need to make the call back function async, so `app.post('/api/screenshot', async (req, res) => {`

Answer (score 4):

You have to `await` the result of `takeScreenShot()`.  It is an `async` function so it returns a promise that eventually resolves to your `screenshot` so to wait for it to complete and to get its value, you have to use either `await` or `.then()` on the promise it returns:

```
app.post('/api/screenshot', async (req, res) => {
  const { url } = req.body

  try {    
      let screenshot = await takeScreenshot(url)
      res.send({ result: screenshot })
  } catch(e) {
      // catch errors and send error status
      console.log(e);
      res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

Changes:

1. Make request handler `async` so you can use `await`.
2. Use `await` to wait for the screenshot result.
3. Add `try/catch` to catch a rejection from the `await`.
4. Send error status if there's an error.

Comment: Thank you! okay i think that fixed it and it no longer pops up as soon as i click the button to initiate the screenshot. But the png file is still corrupted/cannot be opened. Am I not handling the result/res correctly on the front end?

Comment: @Kevin - That is a different problem than you originally ask about.  What is in the `screenshot` variable?  What exactly is that type of data?  If it's binary data, you may need to encode it properly on the server before you send it and then modify the client code to deal with that encoding.

Comment: it is supposed to be a .png file. If I set the path in my takeScreenshot file to save to a local directory, I can open and confirm that the screenshot is taken. But I am just saving that as a variable called 'screenshot' and returning it at the end of the function. On the client side, I create a new Blob with the result and set the type: image/png before generating the link.

Comment: @Kevin - But, what type is the data in the screenshot variable.  Is it a node.js Buffer object containing binary data?  You can't directly send binary data like that as JSON (which is what you're attempting to do).  Instead, you would have to encode it into a string first (often using Base64).  Then, the client would have to decode it to use it.

Comment: yes, I believe you are correct in that it is a Buffer object containing binary data. Let me try to encode it into a string

Answer (score 2):

Try putting async/await function to execute your code one by one like this :

```
 (async() => {
     
      let screenshot = await takeScreenshot(url)
      res.send({ result: screenshot })
    
  })();
```

The `await` function will execute your code and wait it to finish completely and return the final value then it will execute the next command inside the `async` function.