# Express res.write not waiting for array of promises to finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, es6-promise

code

```
const upsertAll = async (types) => {
  let jobs = []
  types.map(type => {
    if (type == "1") jobs.push(asyncFunction1)
    if (type == "2") jobs.push(asyncFunction2)
    if (type == "3") jobs.push(asyncFunction3)
  })
  jobs.reduce((p, fn) => p.then(fn), Promise.resolve())
}
```

```
router.get('/api/generate', async (req, res) => {
  res.write(`${new Date().toISOString()} Generating metadata. Please wait...`);
  const filter = req.query.q.split(',');
  await upsertAll(filter)
  res.write(`${new Date().toISOString()} Done`);
  res.end();
});
```

I want to wait for all promises to complete one-by-one (sequentially like in a series manner)
Then I want express to send the second response message and end

But its not working, all `res.write()` messages are printing at the same time while the promises have not completed yet

i have also tried wrapping

```
res.write(`${new Date().toISOString()} Done`);res.end();
```

in a `upsertAll(filter).then(() =>{})` block but it does not work

related thread 1 [res.send is not waiting for my async function to finish before sending the response to the front end on my Express server app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63865934/res-send-is-not-waiting-for-my-async-function-to-finish-before-sending-the-respo)

related thread 2 https://dev.to/afifsohaili/dealing-with-promises-in-an-array-with-async-await-5d7g

Comment: map? use a simple for loop and actually call the function  `jobs.push(await asyncFunction1())`

Comment: the function calls do happen in async on the reduce line but the router method doesnt work as expected

Comment: see this example: https://playcode.io/791798/ your using map and reduce for no good reason

Comment: link is back. thanks for the example. implementation works with console log statements but in my use case for some reason it does not work with express res (maybe process is blocking). I hit the endpoint and the method gets called but the first res.write never appears on the browser page. during the async, the page is still loading as the tab wheel icon is still spinning. only after the async finishes, the response messages render on the page

Comment: oh right yeah it wouldn't output until res.end is called after all middleware are called, it would be hanging until then, you prob want to use a web socket or SSE if you want a stream of text

Answer (score 0):

try for loop instead

```js
const upsertAll = async (types) => {
  let jobs = []
  for (let i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
    const element = types[i];
    if (type == "1") jobs.push(asyncFunction1)
    if (type == "2") jobs.push(asyncFunction2)
    if (type == "3") jobs.push(asyncFunction3)
  }
  const end = await Promise.all(jobs);
  return end
}
```

or

```js
const upsertAll = async (types) => {
  let jobs = []
  for (let i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
    const element = types[i];
    if (type == "1") jobs.push(await asyncFunction1)
    if (type == "2") jobs.push(await asyncFunction1)
    if (type == "3") jobs.push(await asyncFunction1)
  }
  return jobs
}
```