# res.send() is running before async function call on express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Summary: creating my own API that returns epoch time, and it involves using an express.js server, but it's running res.send() before the function call. I referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63865934/res-send-is-not-waiting-for-my-async-function-to-finish-before-sending-the-respo) page, but it didn't help. Here's what I have:

```
app.get('/timestampAPI', async (req, res,) => {
    try {
        let finalResult  = await getTimeStamp();
        res.send({ something: finalResult });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

It'll start to run the function getTimeStamp(), and before that function finishes, it runs the res.send() function which shows up as '{}' because finalResult doesn't have a value. getTimeStamp() is an async function. I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong.

Edit:
`getTimeStamp()` function:

```
async function getTimeStamp() {
    await axios.get('https://showcase.api.linx.twenty57.net/UnixTime/tounixtimestamp?datetime=now')
        .then(response => {
            // also used console.log(response.data.UnixTimeStamp), which returns the timestamp
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            var errorMessage = error.response.statusText;
            console.log(errorMessage);
        });
    }
```

Another edit: yes, the API referenced above does return the current epoch time, but CORS is blocking my other site from accessing it directly, so I can't use it on that site, which is why I'm using node.js for it so that I can allow myself to access it through my node.js program. Couldn't think of another way

Comment: Are you sure getTimeStamp() is returning a value? To debug, try removing the res.send() line and logging finalResult. The request will hang, but if getTimeStamp is returning a value, you'll see what it is.

Comment: have you logged the finalResult variable to see if it's really a promise?

Comment: @Eduardo It won't be a promise, because `await` returns the value that the promise resolves to.

Comment: The problem is most likely in `getTimeStamp()`, it's not resolving the promise properly. Add that code to the question.

Comment: @Barmar added it to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- returning value of the `then` method does not return from `getTimeStamp` function you should write you code in `resolve` pattern or `using` await like below

try this, make sure you write correct field name in response object

```js
async function getTimeStamp() {
    try{
       const res = await axios.get('https://showcase.api.linx.twenty57.net/UnixTime/tounixtimestamp?datetime=now')
       return res.data
    }catch(error){
      throw error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Mohammad's answer you can also use returning getTimeStamp function's result as a promise and it can solve your problem.

```
async function getTimeStamp() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  axios.get('https://showcase.api.linx.twenty57.net/UnixTime/tounixtimestamp?datetime=now')
    .then(response => {
        // also used console.log(response.data.UnixTimeStamp), which returns the timestamp
        resolve(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        var errorMessage = error.response.statusText;
        console.log(errorMessage);
        reject(error);
    });
})
}
```

Or you would also replace **await** with **return** in getTimeStamp function in your code if you don't want to return promise.(Which is not I recommend.). You should also throw the error in catch block which is generated in getTimeStamp function for catching the error in try-catch block that you use to call app.get(...).